# Stargazer Omit test statistics

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

When using `stargazer` there is an argument, `omit.stat`, however I need to remove the test statistics from below my coefficient values and it isn't an argument listed in the [stargazer package documentation (PDF) (pp. 14–15)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/stargazer.pdf).  Does anyone know how I might go about this?

For Example:

```
install.packages('stargazer'); library(stargazer)
linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning + raises + critical,
               data=attitude)
linear.2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)
attitude$high.rating <- (attitude$rating > 70)
probit.model <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical + advance,
                    data=attitude, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title="Regression Results",
          align=TRUE, dep.var.labels=c("Overall Rating","High Rating"),
          covariate.labels=c("Handling of Complaints","No Special Privileges",
          "Opportunity to Learn","Performance-Based Raises","Too Critical",
          "Advancement"), omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f"), no.space=TRUE)
```

The above gives me a table with test statistics, which I would like to omit entirely. The following replaces them with confidence intervals but that isn't any better.

```
stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, title="Regression Results",
dep.var.labels=c("Overall Rating","High Rating"),
covariate.labels=c("Handling of Complaints","No Special Privileges",
                   "Opportunity to Learn","Performance-Based Raises",
                   "Too Critical","Advancement"), omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f"),
                   ci=TRUE, ci.level=0.90, single.row=TRUE)
```

The tables can be seen on the [R-statistics blog entry, *Tailor Your Tables with stargazer: New Features for LaTeX and Text Output*](http://www.r-statistics.com/2013/07/tailor-your-tables-with-stargazer-new-features-for-latex-and-text-output/), as the first and second respectively.

Comment: Ugh, smart-quotes replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current version of stargazer does not support omitting the standard errors and/or confidence intervals (I assume this is what you mean by 'test statistics'). However, I have been considering making stargazer output a lot more adjustable in future releases - feel free to send me (the package author) ideas about how best to do this.

For now, a hackish way to omit standard errors might involve feeding the `se` argument a list of NAs:

```
stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title="Regression Results", 
align=TRUE, dep.var.labels=c("Overall Rating","High Rating"), 
covariate.labels=c("Handling of Complaints","No Special Privileges", 
"Opportunity to Learn","Performance-Based Raises","Too Critical","Advancement"),
omit.stat=c("LL","ser","f"), no.space=TRUE, se=list(NA, NA, NA))
```

**Update:**

Since version 5.0, stargazer has included the 'report' argument that allows users to choose which statistics to report. To report only coefficients with significance stars, for instance, users can specify `report = "c*"`.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful, I was using the ugly approach of removing every nth line from the output as needed

Comment: passing se=list(NA,NA,NA) works but then the stars for significance are gone as well. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Omitting standard error and/or confidence intervals and keeping the significance stars would be great!

Comment: See the update to my answer above. report = c* might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello, Marek! Do you have any plans to add support for **SEM** packages any time soon? In particular, for objects, produced by `lavaan`, `OpenMx`, `plspm` and other SEM packages. **EFA/CFA** support would be very welcome, as well.

Comment: Planning to make the package more extensible in the near future - would make it easy to add support for those. Currently swamped with other projects, though. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: My pleasure and thank you for the reply. I look forward to the package's enhancements. Best wishes!

Comment: @Marek Would you consider adding a couple of examples with the `report` argument in action in `?stargazer`? This would be very useful!

Comment: @Libby put `se = NA`, it's work for me !