# Including t statistics in regression output using stargazer in R

Tags: r, stargazer

I have three regressions that I am trying to include into one table using the -stargazer- function. I have the following code:

```
library(Jmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(stargazer)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  x2 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  y = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
)

r1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, df)
cov1 <- vcovHC(r1, type="HC1", cluster="clustervar")
robust.se1 <- sqrt(diag(cov1))
t1 <- coef(r1)/robust.se1

r2 <- lm(y ~ x1, df)
cov2 <- vcovHC(r2, type="HC1", cluster="clustervar")
robust.se2 <- sqrt(diag(cov2))
t2 <- coef(r2)/robust.se2

r3 <- lm(y ~ x2, df)
cov3 <- vcovHC(r3, type="HC1", cluster="clustervar")
robust.se3 <- sqrt(diag(cov3))
t3 <- coef(r3)/robust.se2

stargazer(r1, r2, r3, 
se = NULL, 
t = list(t1, t2, t3), 
align=TRUE, 
type="html", 
nobs=TRUE, 
out="StargazerTest.txt")
```

The table that is produced reports standard errors as opposed to the t-statistics I created. This is most likely due to the -stargazer- function at the bottom. I have looked up the directory for it and still don't understand how to get it to do what I want.

Comment: You need to make this more reproducible for Stack Overflow, what is `coef`, how did you create it, what do you mean by "does not work"? Be more specific. Could you make an example that we can copypaste into the console ready-to-run? You need a vector, though, of type `v <- c(1, 1, 1) / 1:3` and put it into a list `list(v)`.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated above to clarify. coef was just a call to the coefficients from that particular regression. It should be much clearer how I use it above now. It is now reproducible. What would I need a vector for here? The t statistics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542583/displaying-p-values-instead-of-ses-in-parenthesis), you can specify the values you want with `report` (since `stargazer` 5.0). In your case, remove `se = NULL` and `t = list(t1, t2, t3)` and put:

```
report = ('c*t')
```

such as:

```
stargazer(r1, r2, r3, 
          report = ('c*t'), 
          align=TRUE, 
          type="html", 
          nobs=TRUE, 
          out="StargazerTest.txt")
```

**Edit:** since you need to use the robust standard error, you should use the function `coeftest` (library `lmtest`) instead of computing the robust standard error manually. Below is an example on one of your regressions:

```
library(Jmisc)
library(tidyverse)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)
library(multiwayvcov)
library(stargazer)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  x2 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1),
  y = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=1)
)

r1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, df)
cov1 <- vcovHC(r1, type="HC1", cluster="clustervar")
robust.se1 <- sqrt(diag(cov1))
t1 <- coef(r1)/robust.se1

foo <- coeftest(r1, vcov = vcovHC(r1, type = "HC1"))

stargazer(foo,  
          report = ('c*t'), 
          align=TRUE, 
          type="html", 
          nobs=TRUE,
          out="StargazerTest.txt")
```

Notice that `foo` gives the same t-values than `t1` but also displays coefficients, se, etc. which allows `stargazer` to work properly

Comment: Thank you, will this make use of the robust standard errors I computed though? I don't directly see how they would be called on here

Comment: hum, I don't think that the robust se are taken into account here. I've found [this](https://economictheoryblog.com/2018/05/18/robust-standard-errors-in-stargazer/) but it does not solve your original problem, I will continue to search

Comment: yeah that is what I had previously because I just wanted to use robust standard errors. I mean I use them in the denominator of when I calculate my t statistics but I think the -report( )- just calculates them based off the regular standard errors computed in the regression

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks I will use this moving forward!

Comment: Happy to help :)